# Would changing URL route in flask break the code?

Tags: python, flask

I initially gave URLs like `@app.route('/volume/')` and `@app.route('/cvolume/')` where `c` denoted another section. But now I think `section/page` would be better than `c` prefix to the page i.e. `@app.route('/c/volume/')`. Can I simply make the change or will this break my app?

P.S. - I am using `<a href="{{url_for("volume")}}>` in templates instead of the plain `<a href="/volume">`

Comment: If your view function is called `volume` then `url_for('volume')` will always generate the correct url for that view. `url_for` is used instead of hardcoding the url precisely to allow such changes without changing other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because `url_for` takes the name of the function, not the url. So if your function is:

```
# ...Code, imports...
@app.route('/cvolume/')
def volume():
    return 'Hello world!'

@app.route('/volume/')
def volume_2():
    return 'Hello You!'

@app.route('/test/')
def test():
    return redirect(url_for('volume'))
```

The redirection would be for `/cvolume/` not `/volume/`.